# Network stack broken after uninstalling AFWall?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, mobile-network

Since uninstalling AFWall and rebooting, I "connect" to LTE/3G/2G and wifi but there is always a little X on the icon and never any network access (can't actually access anything with browsers or apps). GSM voice and SMS works normally.

No connectivity problems via LTE and wifi prior to today. I was messing around with AFWall, applied some rules and enabled/disabled it a couple times. Rebooted once or twice and decided the firewall wasn't blocking/allowing traffic reliably and wasn't logging and showing notifications accurately so uninstalled AFWall and rebooted.

I've had this phone (Zuk Z1) since 2015 and it has been solid. It has been running LOS 16 android 9 for the past 2+ years or so without issue. I've had this same SIM card and provider for over 2 years also.

Troubleshooting already tried:
SIM in other phones works fine
cleared dalvik
cleared SIM tools cache and data
rebooted a couple times
reset APNs

Questions:
Am I missing something obvious? Any suggestions welcome.
Is there an equivalent to "netsh int ip reset" (in windows) for android?
Can I somehow reset iptables to LOS "factory"?
Should I try re-installing AFWall? (if yes, then what?)
I will flash another ROM if necessary, but I'd like to try all other  options first
Thanks for reading!

Comment: AFWall+ only sets firewall rules which aren't persistent across reboots. You can also use `iptables` command to clear all of the firewall chains/rules. Network troubleshooting is almost alike on all OSes. Use `ip` to check routing tables, use `dig` to troubleshoot DNS, and so on. Perform a factory reset if the issue is in Java stack of Android framework.

Comment: RESOLVED: I'm not sure whether to post an answer to my own question or not. I'm not clear on exactly what happened. Resetting iptables (as root) didn't work the first time. I reinstalled AFWall (3.4.0-19450) and rebooted. Then ran "iptables -F && iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT && iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT && iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT" (as root) and uninstalled AFWall and rebooted. There appears to have been a bad interaction between AFWall and an EdXposed module as well. (I don't know exactly what happened, sorry)

Comment: @bumblingfool as long as it solves the issue, feel free to post a [self-answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)!

Comment: Something must be intermittently applying iptable rules at boot because the problem keeps re-occurring sometimes after I restart the phone. I'm still working on it.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to mention that there also exists an option in the reset portion of the settings menu to reset the wireless adapter.

I would have been curious to know if that made a difference.

Comment: Good idea, thanks. I tried it but it didn't make a difference. The issue is with iptable rules intermittently re-applying themselves at reboot it appears...